# how to redirect file write from home folder to specific folder in UNIX

Tags: unix, terminal, redirection

I did a search and didn't find what I was looking for. I finally found a beginners UNIX book that I like. I am going through some examples and I notice output is generated in the home folder. I am using OS X. I keep all my code on my desktop in a folder called code for all my programming assignments and practice. C,C++...etc.

So my question is, how do I do a file redirect from the terminal to create a file in a specific folder? If I type:

> cal 2011 > cal2011

it creates a file called cal2011 to my home folder. How do I write at the terminal without changing directories (the initial command prompt) to save it to:

> desktop/code/unix

Thank you for the help. I am still new at this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are in your homedir, the relative path works.

```
cal 2011 > desktop/code/unix/cal2011
```

If you aren't, you can use the ~ to denote your homedir

```
cal 2011 > ~/desktop/code/unix/cal2011
```

Comment: lil late to the party but thank you.

Comment: Even later, but you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
cal 2011 > /home/<user name>/folder/filename.txt
```

OR

```
cal 2011 > ~/folder/filename.txt
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't redirect to a directory... you need a filename like ~/folder/some_file.

Comment: That's obhious ... right; I was just showing how can we redirect to any specified folder. Anyways, edited.

Comment: Not all Unix-based systems (e.g., Mac OS X, used by the OP) place users' home directories in `/home/username`, and so using a tilde is far more portable.